# memory leak in EWS

Tags: c#-4.0

We have a service application that uses Exchange Web Service. 
We have the memory problem If I call one of the following lines of code in my service, that causes memory leak in my service application.
User application processes a lot of emails, so the memory usage will increase continuously and never be released again.

Code Examples.

```
var item = Item.Bind(mServiceWrapper.Service, ItemId.UniqueId);
var folder = Folder.Bind(mServiceWrapper.Service,item.ParentFolderId.UniqueId);
EmailMessage.Load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent));
```

But if I start our program as an UI application, everything works fine without memory leak.
The problem occurs  only when starting our program as a service.
Is the problem already known to you and do you have a solution?

I am using StreamingSubscript from EWS. Get the Emailas Exchange Server and store it in database.

```
private void OnNotificationEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
{
    var item = Item.Bind(mServiceWrapper.Service, mailItem.ItemId.UniqueId);
    var folder = Folder.Bind(mServiceWrapper.Service, mailItem.ParentFolderId.UniqueId);

    var propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
    item.Load(propertySet);

    folder.Load(PropertiesProvider.FolderPropertySet);

    object[] data = new object[]
                                {
                                    item.Id.UniqueId,
                                    folder.Id.UniqueId,
                                    folder.ExtendedProperties.GetPropertyValue<long>(@"LexolutionContainerId"),
                                    folder.ExtendedProperties.GetPropertyValue<int>(@"TrayId")
                                };

}
```

Another thread will load the emails and process the emails again. Like this

```
protected override void InternalWork(IJob job)
{
    try
    {
        object[] data = (object[]) job.DataObject;
        string itemUniqueId = (string) data[0];
        ItemId itemId = new ItemId(itemUniqueId);
        long targetContainerId = (long) data[2];

        var propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent,
                        EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId);
        var mail = Item.Bind(ExchangeWrapper.Service, itemId, propertySet);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really give us enough code to be able to say for sure what your problem is -- but I can guess that you are not disposing of items correctly and/or the GC is not being called.

As a first step (and a general practice) I'd re-factor your code to use the using statement.  Thus the code above would look like this:

```
var item = Item.Bind(mServiceWrapper.Service, ItemId.UniqueId);
var folder = Folder.Bind(mServiceWrapper.Service,item.ParentFolderId.UniqueId);
using (var props = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent))
{
  EmailMessage.Load(props);
  // additional code
}
```

There may be other places you can use using in your code, here is some documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

In addition you should look into forcing the GC to run in a service.  This may be your problem too.

Comment: On server start  I sync

Comment: I don't know what that mean @Zhentao

Comment: Is it possible memory leak by using Item.Bind?

Comment: If I start my application as UI, then I don't have memory problem

Comment: I know that @Zhentao you said that in your question.  That is why I said what I said in my answer.  Did you read my answer?